# How to make async requests using HTTPoison?

Tags: asynchronous, elixir, httpoison

### Background

We have an app that deals with a considerable amount of requests per second. This app needs to notify an external service, by making a GET call via HTTPS to one of our servers.

### Objective

The objective here is to use HTTPoison to make async GET requests. I don't really care about the response of the requests, all I care is to know if they failed or not, so I can write any possible errors into a logger.

If it succeeds I don't want to do anything.

### Research

I have checked the official documentation for HTTPoison and I see that they support async requests:

https://hexdocs.pm/httpoison/readme.html#usage

However, I have 2 issues with this approach:

1. They use `flush` to show the request was completed. I can't loggin into the app and manually `flush` to see how the requests are going, that would be insane.
2. They don't show any notifications mechanism for when we get the responses or errors.

So, I have a simple question:

1. How do I get asynchronously notified that my request failed or succeeded?

I assume that the default `HTTPoison.get` is synchronous, as shown in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be achieved by spawning a new process per-request. Consider something like:

```
notify = fn response ->
  # Any handling logic - write do DB? Send a message to another process?
  # Here, I'll just print the result
  IO.inspect(response)
end

spawn(fn ->
  resp = HTTPoison.get("http://google.com")
  notify.(resp)
end) # spawn will not block, so it will attempt to execute next spawn straig away

spawn(fn ->
  resp = HTTPoison.get("http://yahoo.com")
  notify.(resp)
end) # This will be executed immediately after previoius `spawn`
```

Please take a look at the documentation of [`spawn/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#spawn/1) I've pointed out here.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I would recommend at the very least using `Task.start_link` instead of `spawn` - `spawn` does not link the created process to anything, so if it fails unexpectedly you will never find out.